Modifying floating point context from within signal handler
I am attempting to write a C signal handler for floating point exceptions that can log an exception, then return back to original function with floating point exceptions disabled to continue with nonfinite results.  I do have a working example in windows, and now attempting to port to linux x64 platform.
I've gotten so far as configuring the floating point unit in the main program and setting up a signal handler, as shown in the program below.
I've attempted the strategy from the above linked windows version, which modifies the context pointer passed into the signal handler to reset the floating point unit flags.  However, in this attempt, the program seg-faults when the signal handler returns.
I'm wondering if what I'm attempting here is possible at all?  The goal here would be such that this program could complete showing that it's captured 1 SIGFPE.
Heck, if I can do it in Windows, surely there's a way in Linux?
NOTE: Below program will attempt the floating point context alteration if it recieves any command line argument, otherwise it enters an infinite loop re-catching the first fpe.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fenv.h>
#include <ucontext.h>
#include <signal.h>

/* zero value as global to prevent compiler optimization */
double zero_val = 0.0;

/* global controlling behavior of sig handler*/
int flag_enable_fpe_context_reset = 0;

/* globals to be updated by signal handler */
int num_fpe_signals = 0;
int last_fpe_signum = 0;
siginfo_t last_fpe_siginfo;
ucontext_t last_fpe_context;


void my_fpe_signal_handler(int signum, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context){
    /* 0. local variable declaration */
    ucontext_t MyContext;
    fenv_t    fe_excepts;
    
    write(STDERR_FILENO , "CAUGHT SIGFPE!\n" , 15);

    /* 1. Cast context to proper pointer type
     *   ref: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/sigaction.html
     */
    ucontext_t *pCallerContext = (ucontext_t*) context;

    /* 2. Log this exception into global variables
     * (for later inspection)
     */
    num_fpe_signals++;
    last_fpe_signum  = signum;
    last_fpe_siginfo = *siginfo;
    last_fpe_context = *pCallerContext;

    /* 3. attempting to modify return context to disable exceptions
     *    using feholdexcept() which returns floating point state to
     *    a "default" which does not throw exceptions.  Assuming this
     *    modifies the current context so we can copy it to the callers
     *    context
     */
    feholdexcept(&fe_excepts);

    /* 4. capture the current context, assuming it's floating point
     *    environment has been modified by feholdexcept() above.
     */
    getcontext(&MyContext);

    /* 5. Copy the floating point configuration 
     *    from MyContext to caller context,
     *    in an attempt to disable future floating point exceptions,
     *    allowing program to proceed with nonfinite results.
     */
    if(flag_enable_fpe_context_reset){
        pCallerContext->uc_mcontext.fpregs = MyContext.uc_mcontext.fpregs;
    }
    
    /* 6. Infinite Loop Detector
     */
    if(num_fpe_signals > 10){
        write(STDERR_FILENO, "Infinite loop detection triggered. Exiting Program From Signal Handler!\n",72);
        fflush(stderr);
        _Exit(1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[] ){
    /* local variable declarations */
    double retval;
    
    /* if program gets more than 1 argument, then enable 
     * flag_enable_fpe_context_reset
     */
    if(argc > 1){
        flag_enable_fpe_context_reset = 1;
    }

    /* Setup signal handler with SA_SIGINFO flag 
     * for 3-argument calling syntax including context 
     * See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html
     */
    struct sigaction sig_action = {};
    sig_action.sa_sigaction = my_fpe_signal_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sig_action.sa_mask);
    sig_action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO; 
    if (sigaction(SIGFPE,  &sig_action, NULL) != 0) { err(1, "sigaction"); }

    /* Enable floating exceptions */
    feenableexcept( FE_INVALID | FE_DIVBYZERO | FE_OVERFLOW );

    /* do some math -- expect to enter signal handler here */
    retval = 5.0/zero_val;
    printf("5.0/zero_val = %f\n",retval);

    /* do some more math -- expect that signal handler has 
     * disabled exceptions by now, do not re-enter signal handler
     */
    retval = 6.0/zero_val;
    printf("6.0/zero_val = %f\n",retval);

    /* print info about captured signals 
     * (todo -- convert context to line-number using debug info)
     */
    printf("num_fpe_signals = %d\n" , num_fpe_signals);
}


Linux port is working now. Issue was attempting to copy the entire fpregs substruct, works now copying individual fields.
Not totally sure this is completely correct, as I haven't found any robust references for this sort of thing, but it works!
Updated program below:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fenv.h>
#include <ucontext.h>
#include <signal.h>

/* zero value as global to prevent compiler optimization */
double zero_val = 0.0;

/* global controlling behavior of sig handler*/
int flag_enable_fpe_context_reset = 1;

/* globals to be updated by signal handler */
int num_fpe_signals = 0;
int last_fpe_signum = 0;
siginfo_t last_fpe_siginfo;
ucontext_t last_fpe_context;


void my_fpe_signal_handler(int signum, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context){
    /* 0. local variable declaration */
    ucontext_t MyContext;
    fenv_t    fe_excepts;
    
    write(STDERR_FILENO , "CAUGHT SIGFPE!\n" , 15);

    /* 1. Cast context to proper pointer type
     *   ref: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/sigaction.html
     */
    ucontext_t *pCallerContext = (ucontext_t*) context;

    /* 2. Log this exception into global variables
     * (for later inspection)
     */
    num_fpe_signals++;
    last_fpe_signum  = signum;
    last_fpe_siginfo = *siginfo;
    last_fpe_context = *pCallerContext;

    /* 3. attempting to modify return context to disable exceptions
     *    using feholdexcept() which returns floating point state to
     *    a "default" which does not throw exceptions.  Assuming this
     *    modifies the current context so we can copy it to the callers
     *    context
     */
    feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    fedisableexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT); // Disable floating point exceptions
    //feholdexcept(&fe_excepts);
    

    /* 4. capture the current context, assuming it's floating point
     *    environment has been modified by feholdexcept() above.
     */
    getcontext(&MyContext);

    /* 5. Copy the floating point configuration 
     *    from MyContext to caller context,
     *    in an attempt to disable future floating point exceptions,
     *    allowing program to proceed with nonfinite results.
     */
    if(flag_enable_fpe_context_reset){
        pCallerContext->uc_mcontext.fpregs->mxcsr     = MyContext.uc_mcontext.fpregs->mxcsr;
        pCallerContext->uc_mcontext.fpregs->mxcr_mask = MyContext.uc_mcontext.fpregs->mxcr_mask;
        pCallerContext->uc_mcontext.fpregs->cwd       = MyContext.uc_mcontext.fpregs->cwd;
        pCallerContext->uc_mcontext.fpregs->swd       = MyContext.uc_mcontext.fpregs->swd;
    }
    
    /* 6. Infinite Loop Detector
     */
    if(num_fpe_signals > 10){
        write(STDERR_FILENO, "Infinite loop detection triggered. Exiting Program From Signal Handler!\n",72);
        fflush(stderr);
        _Exit(1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[] ){
    /* local variable declarations */
    double retval;
    
    /* if program gets more than 1 argument, then disable
     * flag_enable_fpe_context_reset
     */
    if(argc > 1){
        flag_enable_fpe_context_reset = 0;
    }

    /* Setup signal handler with SA_SIGINFO flag 
     * for 3-argument calling syntax including context 
     * See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html
     */
    struct sigaction sig_action = {};
    sig_action.sa_sigaction = my_fpe_signal_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sig_action.sa_mask);
    sig_action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO; 
    if (sigaction(SIGFPE,  &sig_action, NULL) != 0) { err(1, "sigaction"); }

    /* Enable floating exceptions */
    feenableexcept( FE_INVALID | FE_DIVBYZERO | FE_OVERFLOW );

    /* do some math -- expect to enter signal handler here */
    retval = 5.0/zero_val;
    printf("5.0/zero_val = %f\n",retval);

    /* do some more math -- expect that signal handler has 
     * disabled exceptions by now, do not re-enter signal handler
     */
    retval = 6.0/zero_val;
    printf("6.0/zero_val = %f\n",retval);

    /* print info about captured signals 
     * (todo -- convert context to line-number using debug info)
     */
    printf("num_fpe_signals = %d\n" , num_fpe_signals);
}

